# What is an alternative to the Excel LET function that can be used in a Microsoft List calculated column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-columns, sharepoint-list

Using a calculated column, I am trying to output a number based on the values of multiple columns.

I have a solution working in Excel that utilises the [LET function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999)

When I try and use the `LET` function in a Microsoft List calculated column, I get an error on save that the formula is wrong or the function is not supported etc.

This is what I entered in the calculated column formula area:

```
=LET(a, IF([Stage 01 Status]="Completed", 1), b, IF([Stage 02 Status]="Completed",1), c, IF([Stage 03 Status]="Completed",1), d, IF([Stage 04 Status]="Completed",1), e, IF([Stage 05 Status]="Completed",1), a+b+c+d+e)
```

In pseudo code, this is what it means:

IF `Stage 01 Status` is equal to `Completed`, then let the variable `a` equal `1`.
IF `Stage 02 Status` is equal to `Completed`, then let the variable `b` equal `1`.
IF `Stage 03 Status` is equal to `Completed`, then let the variable `c` equal `1`.
IF `Stage 04 Status` is equal to `Completed`, then let the variable `d` equal `1`.
IF `Stage 05 Status` is equal to `Completed`, then let the variable `e` equal `1`.
FINALLY, OUTPUT the SUM of `a` and `b` and `c` and `d` and `e`.

So, if a user had Completed 3 stages, it would output the number 3.

If a user had Completed 5 stages, it would output the number 5 etc.

Can anyone please tell me if there is an alternative to `LET` that can be used in a calculated column?

Or, if there is no alternative, suggest a way that I can produce the same desired output?

**EDIT:**

Below is the formula in an Excel context:

```
=LET(a, IF(D2="Completed", 1), b, IF(D3="Completed",1), c, IF(D4="Completed",1), d, IF(D5="Completed",1), e, IF(D6="Completed",1), a+b+c+d+e)
```

And a screenshot to show that it works:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve the desired behaviour:

```
=IF([Stage 01 Status]="Completed",1)+IF([Stage 02 Status]="Completed",1)+IF([Stage 03 Status]="Completed",1)+IF([Stage 04 Status]="Completed",1+IF([Stage 05 Status]="Completed",1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula for your SharePoint calculated column:

```
=IF([Stage 01 Status]="Completed",1,0)+IF([Stage 02 Status]="Completed",1,0)+IF([Stage 03 Status]="Completed",1,0)+IF([Stage 04 Status]="Completed",1,0)+IF([Stage 05 Status]="Completed",1,0)
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))